# How to set a default value for key in dict, when the key value is not found in the dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to scrape some results from ebay with python and I am running into an error :

```
condition = item['condition'][0]['conditionDisplayName'][0]
>>> KeyError: 'condition'`
```

This is the code in question :

```
for item in (parseddoc["findItemsByKeywordsResponse"][0] ["searchResult"][0]["item"]):
    condition = item['condition'][0]['conditionDisplayName'][0]
    print(condition)
```

I am trying to figure out a way to stop it from getting the error and just default to a preset value`( "N/A" for example )` and continue with the loop. What's the best way to achieve that? Thanks

Comment: Lookup `defaultdict`

Comment: A defaultdict would generate the "condition" key, not default to somthing other if not present

Comment: consider putting your `condition = ` in a try block and if exception is thrown change value to "N/A"

Answer (score 3):

Use a `try` / `except` clause to catch `KeyError`:

```
for item in parseddoc["findItemsByKeywordsResponse"][0]["searchResult"][0]["item"]:

    try:
        condition = item['condition'][0]['conditionDisplayName'][0]
    except KeyError:
        condition = 'N/A'

    print(condition)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following if/else statement to your loop:

```
for item in (parseddoc["findItemsByKeywordsResponse"][0]["searchResult"][0]["item"]):
    if 'condition' not in item:
        condition = 'N/A'
    else:
        condition = item['condition'][0]['conditionDisplayName'][0]
    print(condition)
```